# How to handle authorization and work with multiple pages in React MPA

Tags: reactjs

I need to add authorization to multiple pages / components in my react app, how can I do that without repeating the same fetch()? Basically just checking, if im logged in or not, so that i can display appropriate buttons on navbar and move user to login page in some cases. 
Should I create a component with a callback that will return boolean with info if im logged in or not?

Also right now I have one big component for each url, which renders navbar component and usually only one actual component in the right place in UI, is that a good practice?

Anything I should do while moving from page to page? Ive noticed that I need to clear setIntervals, anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a HOC (Higher Order Component).

Sahil Mittal wrote a good article explaining how to create HOC for authenticated routing: https://www.codementor.io/sahilmittal/using-higher-order-components-for-authenticated-routing-i1hcp6pc6